# Using LINQ to fill the list with the latest available value

Tags: c#, linq, time-series

I have one data object that holds

1. the announcement date of a certain report,
2. and the value announced at that date

i.e. the class would look like:

```
    class Report
    {
    DateTime announcementDate;
    double ValueAnnounced;
    }
```

So, consider a list of Report with the following values:

```
    List<Report> reports = new List<Report>;
    Report newReport = new Report();
    newReport.announcementDate =Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/2011"); newReport.ValueAnnounced = 5;reports.Add(newReport);
    newReport.announcementDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2/1/2011"); newReport.ValueAnnounced = 10;reports.Add(newReport);
    newReport.announcementDate = Convert.ToDateTime("3/1/2011"); newReport.ValueAnnounced = 15;reports.Add(newReport);
```

Now, what i need is, I need to create a new list "that will have the latest value announced for each of the calendar date from 1/1/2011 to 3/31/2011."

i.e. the linq will return a list which will have the following elements:

```
    dailyReport[0].calendarDate = 1/1/2011; dailyReport[0].latestValue = 5;
    dailyReport[1].calendarDate = 1/2/2011; dailyReport[2].latestValue = 5;
    dailyReport[2].calendarDate = 1/3/2011; dailyReport[3].latestValue = 5;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    dailyReport[30].calendarDate = 2/1/2011; dailyReport[30].latestValue = 10;
    dailyReport[31].calendarDate = 2/2/2011; dailyReport[31]latestValue = 10;
    dailyReport[32].calendarDate = 2/3/2011; dailyReport[32].latestValue = 10;
    dailyReport[33].calendarDate = 2/4/2011; dailyReport[33].latestValue = 10;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    dailyReport[60].calendarDate = 3/1/2011; dailyReport[60].latestValue = 15;
    dailyReport[61].calendarDate = 3/2/2011; dailyReport[61].latestValue = 15;
    dailyReport[62].calendarDate = 3/3/2011; dailyReport[62].latestValue = 15;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    dailyReport[90].calendarDate = 3/31/2011; dailyReport[62].latestValue = 15;
```

I can already generate that dailyReport list with the help of this loop:

```
    List<Report> dailyReport = new List<Report>;


    foreach (DateTime calendarDay in EachDay(StartDate, EndDate))
    {
            var latestAvailableReport =
                (
                from theReport in reports
                where theReport.announcementDate <= calendarDay
                orderby theReport.announcementDate descending
                select theReport
                ).ToList();

            Report newDailyReport = new Report();
            newDailyReport.announcementDate = latestAvailableReport[0].announcementDate;
            newDailyReport.ValueAnnounced = latestAvailableReport[0].ValueAnnounced;
            dailyReport.Add(newDailyReport);

    }
```

and the supportive method EachDay would look like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> EachDay(DateTime from, DateTime thru)
    {
        for(var day = from.Date; day.Date <= thru.Date; day =day.AddDays(1))
        yield return day;
    }
```

My question however is that, I can sense that there should be faster (or more elegant at the very least) ways to generate that dailyReport list - which basically is the "fill in with latest value" version of the original list.

I think that elegant way is obviously a clever LINQ design - which I could not figure out given my current knowledge and capabilities.

Could you please help me in writing that LINQ please?

Thanks in advance for your interest and time, very much appreciated.

Aykut Saribiyik

Comment: LINQ is not a magic, first convert your code so that you use a loop. Then think how it can be translated to Linq.

Comment: Thanks for the comment EZI. Your comment helps noone in any way but it is duly noted. Thanks for the time.

Comment: Aykut Saribiyik, I disagree, People will know what/how not to ask, when reading that comment.

Comment: I agree with EZI (and note that his comment has been up-voted 3 times). Anytime you're unsure how to do something in LINQ, try it first in a regular loop. When that's working, converting to LINQ is not hard, and is something you could get help with here. Also note that LINQ gets unreadable fairly quickly if you try to do to much in one statement. Sometimes standard loops are the best way just for debugging and maintainability.

Comment: Your sample class code does not compile. Uppercase `Class` is not a keyword, and `Datetime` without a capital 'T' in time is not a built in class or struct.

Comment: Dear @EZI, "think how it can be translated to Linq" is not an answer, sorry. When someone asks a question at stackoverflow, anyone would/should know that the owner of the question has "already" thought how it can be translated to Linq", and he could not come up with a solution. Otherwise, I would not be asking for help, would not I? So; if I may repeat, yes, people will now know how/what not to answer when reading your comment. Please look at dasblinkenlight's comments below on how a decent, positive, contributing answer and/or comments would look like.

Comment: Thanks @Rufus for the positive approach to the question. I will now review my question once again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve? You are asking how to write a good code for your problem, but there is no such thing as a good code by itself, it's always good for something: for performance, for memory usage, for readability and maintainability etc.

What are you doing now is you're trying to improve performance but make memory usage and maintainability worse.

If I were you, I would first write code like this:

```
public static class ReportListExtensions
{
    public static Report GetReport(this IEnumerable<Report> reports, DateTime date)
    {
        return new Report
        {
            AnnouncementDate = date,
            ValueAnnounced = reports.OrderByDescending(r => r.AnnouncementDate)
                                    .First(r => r.AnnouncementDate < date)
                                    .ValueAnnounced
        };
    }
}
```

This solution is very simple, readable and maintainable. You don't even have to touch your current code to use this functionality. Later you can take a profiler to see if you have some performance issues and easily improve this code (preventive ordering, caching and so on).

It certainly is not an answer to your question, but it might help you to realize that maybe you are trying so solve a problem that doesn't exist.